# What is the replacement for java.util.Timer.purge() in codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to port some java code to codenameone. A portion of the code uses java.util.Timer. It appears though that codenameone does not support Timer.purge(). Is there any way to achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I actually never used that API so I had to check what it does in the JavaDocs:

> Removes all cancelled tasks from this timer's task queue. Calling this
>   method has no effect on the behavior of the timer, but eliminates the
>   references to the cancelled tasks from the queue. If there are no
>   external references to these tasks, they become eligible for garbage
>   collection.
>
> Most programs will have no need to call this method. It is designed
>   for use by the rare application that cancels a large number of tasks.
>   Calling this method trades time for space: the runtime of the method
>   may be proportional to n + c log n, where n is the number of tasks in
>   the queue and c is the number of cancelled tasks.

The way I read this the method is an unnecessary. If you need to cancel so many timers that purge becomes essential you might prefer graduating to using a thread which might be more efficient.

Comment: Ok. I will remove it and see what happens.